# Wait for imported puppeteer function to finish then start a new line nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have this code

```js
const poro = require('./poro.js')

let searchResult = poro.search()

console.log(searchResult)
```

search() is a puppeteer function in the ./poro file that takes around 5 seconds to finish.

I want it to wait until searchResult gets a value then move on to log.

Comment: if the search function is asynchronous then add an `await` in front of the `poro.search()`

Comment: I would make whatever that function is return a promise

Comment: Done await works now

Answer (score 1):

You just try this

```
const poro = require('./poro.js');

async function searchResult(){
   let searchResult = await poro.search()
   console.log(searchResult)
};

searchResult();
```

Comment: I had to make search() async for this solution to work, but yeah it is correct.